# Angular 6 Can't loop through property after response

Tags: angular, loops, properties, components

I'm actually new to angular. I'm trying to loop through a property inside the component file, but i always get the Message that the property legnth is undefined.

[Screenshot Chrome DevTools Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbzi5.png)

this is my component file. If i loop through the rooms property from my HTML File wit ngFor it works perfectly but inside the component itself i cant access the property. Need some help

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { AddRoomService } from '../../_services/addroom.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';

declare var $: any;

declare interface Room {

  name?: string;
  floor?: number;
  maxseats?: number;
  maxcapacity?: number;
  flipchartcount?: number;
  moderationbagcount?: number;
  laptopscount?: number;
  moderationmaterialcount?: number;
}

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'addRoom-cmp',
  templateUrl: './add.component.html',
  providers: [NgForm, AddRoomService]
})

export class AddComponent implements OnInit {

  public typeValidation: Room;

  simpleSlider = 0;
  locations: any;
  rooms: any;
  model: any = {};

  constructor(private addRoomService: AddRoomService, private http: HttpClient) {   

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    this.typeValidation = {
      name: '',
    }    

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {    

    this.getHappeningLocations();
    this.getExistingRooms();

    for (let room of this.rooms) {
      console.log(room);
    }      

  }

  getHappeningLocations() {
    this.http.get('https://localhost:44368/api/HappeningLocation/').subscribe(response => {
      this.locations = response;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  getExistingRooms() {
    this.http.get('https://localhost:44368/api/room/getallrooms').subscribe(response => {
      this.rooms = response;      
      //console.log(response);      
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

EDIT:

i changed it like below, now it works perfectly, thank you for your help :)

```
getHappeningLocations() {
    this.http.get('https://localhost:44368/api/HappeningLocation/').subscribe(response => {
      this.locations = response;
      this.getExistingRooms(response);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  getExistingRooms(locations: any) {
    this.http.get('https://localhost:44368/api/room/getallrooms').subscribe(response => {
      this.rooms = response;

      for (let room of this.rooms) {
        console.log(room);
      }

      for (let loc of locations) {
        console.log(loc);
      }
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hey Jimmy, if you put the loop in the subscribe function of  getExistingRooms() can you loop through from there? I think this.rooms isn't set when you get to the for loop because everything happens asynchronously, it;s not waiting for your 
 getExistingRooms method to set this.rooms before it loops through them.

Comment: Hi, a "reduced" version of your coding would be nice.  -- Because of the error message i think, that you have somewhere (in TS or in your template) a "myArray.length". But if "myArray" is not initalized (mostly because it is filled by an async call, like your HTTP Calls), then the "length" is called on an undefined value => "Cannot read property "length" of undefined" :-). --- In your TS-Coding a can´t see such a variable, could it be that you have one in your template "add.component.html" ???  
Warm regards

Comment: Hey Dan, jeah if i do it in the subscribe function it will do itÄs job, but i neet to push some data from the other subscribe functions in the rooms array so i need to do it outside of the subscribe function

Comment: @jen, yeah, that's what I'm saying, Jimmy needs to set then work with this.rooms inside the subscribe function of his getExistingRooms function so the array isn't undefined. Asynchronous can be tricky if you haven;t worked with it before but you get the hang of it soon enough.

Comment: Hi Jan which part do you need?

Comment: @jimmy You can pass the rooms array data to the other function in the getExistingRooms subscribe function, then make that call and do whatever you need in the latter calls' subscribe function, would that work?

Comment: Hey @JimmyPage you won't get `this.room` in the loop there, because when `this.getExistingRooms()` runs it get's to api to fetch the result till then javascript won't wait for the response to get back and hence will move onto the next step i.e. in your for loop and at that time `this.room` is undefined and this is the beauty of asynchronous way. To loop over to `this.room` you have to put the loop inside your subscribe method

Comment: @Dan Hmm maybe it'll work, i have to try it. so i move the getExistingRooms function call from the ngAfterViewInit into the get happeningLocation subscribe function. did i understand that correctly?

Comment: @Suryan Hmm ok then i have to try it from the other subscribe Function and pass the response as parameter to it

Comment: Yeah, I think a good rule of thumb is just to know that if you want to work with a http response in angular you need to subscibe to it and use it in the subscribe function, from within the subscribe function you can pass it to another function, or set it, or do what you want. Good luck!

Comment: what if you write if(this.room.length) { // }

Comment: @JimmyPage feel free to mark my answer as the correct one if I helped. Good luck again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set and then use this.rooms within the subscribe function of your getExistingRooms() function. In this subscribe function you can pass it to another function if you need to work with the data more.

The asynchronous nature of angular means you don't have this.rooms set when you try to loop over it, the thread just continues, it doesn't wait for the http call to respond before moving on. You need to work with the responses within the subscribe functions on http calls.

For further reading you can check out

```
https://angular.io/guide/observables
```

It gives you an idea of how subscribing to Observables means you can work with the data returned from a http call.